# Undoing sudo chmod 750 lib

Tags: permissions

So I deliberately changed permission of the /lib folder to 750.  Not recursive.  I'm now faced with

```
-bash: /bin/ls: Permission denied
```

and (much more problematic)

```
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

errors.  So one thing I need to figure out is how to fix this problem (live-cd... but this is a headless server with DisplayPort only and no DP monitors available, so that's going to suck), but mostly... why did this happen?

I admit, *nix permissions have always messed with my head.  Why is changing the world view of my lib folder making it so I can't do anything?  Had I done 751 would I have been OK?  Had I had my own user added to the root group would I have been OK (but that seems like a bad idea)?

Thanks.

[edit]

As requested in comments, here are the pertinent getfacl results (identical for lib, bin and usr after fixing /lib back to 755):

```
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Comment: I had typed out an answer and then on further inspection realized it didn't make sense because your problem seems deeper. How did changing /lib affect /usr/bin?

Which distribution are you using here specifically?

Comment: Good question.  I was in / and typed exactly:  sudo chmod 750 lib
that's it.  I figured sudo must have been in there.  I'm running Ubuntu server 18.04

Comment: I'm looking at an 1804 setup right now and it doesn't seem to have those files in lib, and instead seems to have them in /bin.

Can you please run `getfacl /lib` and `getfacl /bin` and well for completeness you might as well include `getfacl /usr` and edit your question with results?

Comment: Would love to, but now I can't log in at all.  Grr

Comment: I realized after I asked you wouldn't be able to anyways... I think at the point you're at now, it's live dvd time, mount the drive and change the permissions back to default (755). I've taken the liberty of breaking a virtual machine the same way, and it would seem to me the quickest way to resolve this is going to be live boot. Perhaps someone smarter than me will be along to help if you are patient.

Comment: I'm not patient, and I have it back up and running (I managed to hook a keyboard up to it, hit shift during boot and enter the commands blind!  lol).  I've updated with your getfacl data, but of course lib is back to 755 now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103440/discussion-between-bcsteeve-and-dave).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it back up and running.

I've now tried again with 751 instead of 750 and it appears to work.  I guess the 0 made all the libraries blind to the currently logged in user, since that folder is owned by root:root and I'm not a member of root.  Sudo (etc) depends on the libraries and there was no executable bit.  751 sets executable to the world, so that resolved it.  Am I going to run into other troubles with 751?   We'll see ;)